# How to use Go Get on azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In theory, given that Azure now includes go support by default, I should be able to run:

go get github.com/etsy/hound/cmds/...

and have Azure pull down the necessary files but when I run that I get the following:

> D:\home\site\wwwroot
>   'go' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I cd to d:\program files\go\1.7\bin and run it again I get:

> D:\Program Files\Go\1.7\bin
>   go: cannot find GOROOT directory: c:\go

Is this simply a limitation of Azure web apps?

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

After you install Go Lang for Azure Websites, please restart the site to make it available and you need to ensure Go binaries (found in D:\home\site\wwwroot\go\bin) are in Path system environment variables. You could add a folder to the PATH through an [XDT Transform](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples).

```
<environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">    
  <add name="PATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\go\bin" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
</environmentVariables>
```

[image]

Besides, as far as I know, you should also add **GOROOT** and **GOPATH** to environment variables.

Comment: Hi Fred,

Given the path I mentioned, I had assumed that the Go Lang binaries were already installed by default; is this not the case?

If not, how do I do that? especially given that I cannot seem to access c: or do much more than mkdir using the azure Webapp console. (In case you hadn't guessed I'm a complete n00b when it comes to Azure...)

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Go [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure) blade > App settings, and add GOROOT (set value to ``%HOME%\\site\\wwwroot\\go``) and GOPATH (set value to ``%HOME%\\site\\wwwroot\\gopath``).